# In Java how do you read n-bits from a byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit

I am trying to parse data from a specific ByteArray I'm receiving via Bluetooth from my blood pressure cuff. According to this specification [GATT Appearance Characteristic Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml) the data is a 16-bit byte array with two values—a category (10-bits) and sub-categories (6-bits). I do not have the knowledge of how to read values that aren't stored in a byte(s). How do you read 10 of 16 and 6 of 16 bits from a byte array? Then once I have 10-bits do I have to pad it with 6 zeros to get a value? I'm assuming these aren't flags of course are potentially string values.

I have been trying to understand various [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Bitwise-Operators) and [guides](https://www.developer.com/java/data/using-the-java-bit-manipulation-operators.html#:~:text=In%20Java%2C%20there%20is%20a,short%2C%20int%2C%20and%20long.) on Bitwise operations and it just doesn't click with how to read 10 bits.

```
deviceConnection =
            device.establishConnection(true)
                .flatMapSingle {
                    for (g in gattCharacteristics) {
                        singles.add(it.readCharacteristic(g.uuid))                        
                    }
                    Single.zip(
                        singles
                    ) { varargs ->
                        val values: MutableList<ByteArray> = mutableListOf()
                        for (v in varargs) {
                            values.add(v as ByteArray)
                        }
                        return@zip values
                    }
                }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .take(1)
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        characteristics.forEachIndexed { index, c ->
                            c.value = processByteArray(c.uuid, it[index])
                        }
                        serviceDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    },
                    {
                        onConnectionFailure(it)
                    }
                )
```

Then in the `processByteArray` function I need to figure out how to parse the data.

Comment: How are you reading the data using java? Which methods are you using? How do you obtain the data? Be more specific. You are reading two 2 bytes (16 bits), how are you getting them?

Comment: @Snix I added the code I've written to read the characteristic. It's written in Kotlin and I am implementing RxJava and the RxAndroidBle library. I have to handle the parsing of the data, however, and I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the amounts are not aligned to 8-bit bytes, to make things easier first put the two bytes together:

```java
byte mostSignifant = byteArray[0];
byte leastSignifant =byteArray[1];
int bothBytes = (Byte.toUnsignedInt(mostSignifant) << 8) | Byte.toUnsignedInt(leastSignifant);
```

Your documentation should tell you which of the two bytes is the "most significant byte" (MSB) and which is the least (LSB) - it could be that index 0 has the least significant byte.

Now you can extract the bits you want, for example

```java
int lower6Bits = bothBytes & 0b111111;
int higher10Bits = bothBytes >>> 6; // get rid of lower 6 bits
```